# Examining subset of observations in Linear Model in R

Tags: r, model, lm

In r, I have a linear model titled lmod452.  From this linear model, I want to examine observations from case numbers 25-50 to observe which are an anomoly.  How do I use the plot function on a select number of observations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` to subset data.  So for fake data

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + 0.5*rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
```

...you can plot a subset of observations...

```
plot(x[25:50], y[25:50])
```

...or overlay them using a different plotting character or color...

```
plot(x,y)
points(x[25:50], y[25:50], pch=16, col="red")
```

Lots of ways to go, hopefully this gets you started.

Oh, and since you mention your lm model and not your data, it's worth noting that you can extract the data from an lm object.  Just call `names(lmod452$model)` to get the names.

```
lmod452 <- lm(y~x)

# extracting stuff
xxx <- lmod452$model$x
yyy <- lmod452$model$y
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't follow you code to get it to work.

I tried:

> x <- lmod452$model$x
> y <- lmod452$model$y
> plot(x[25:50],y[25:50])
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

I then tried defining xlim= and ylim= and it wouldn't work with NULL or #s.

I truly appreciate your help

Comment: Hm - I had hoped the data would be extractable that way. It might take a bit of digging with str(lmod452) to see where the data are. The cleanest solution would be to use the original data, if available.